# How to toggle on / off? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, toggle

I'm trying out JS without jQuery. But so far it's much harder.

I'm trying to make a toggle on & off function.

This is the function:

```
function toggleDropdown(){

   var dropdown = document.getElementById('games-dropdown')

   if (dropdown.display = "none"){
    dropdown.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
    dropdown.display = "none";
   }
}
```

I call the function here:

```
<li class="dropdown"><a onclick="toggleDropdown()">GAMES</a></li>
```

Comment: A CSS Class would be so much easier. `dropdown.classList.toggle("enabled")`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks, checked it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not being consistent about using the `style` object, you're checking and sometimes setting `display` directly on `dropdown`.

You're also using `=` instead of `==` for comparison. `=` is for *assignment*, not comparison.

So the minimal change is:

```
function toggleDropdown(){

   var dropdown = document.getElementById('games-dropdown')

   // ----------vvvvv    
   if (dropdown.style.display == "none"){
   // ------------------------^^
     dropdown.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
     dropdown.style.display = "none";
   // --------^^^^^^
   }
}
```

**However**, I wouldn't use `style` at all. I'd use a class that hides the element, which you add and remove:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and

```
function toggleDropdown(){
   document.getElementById('games-dropdown').classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

Example:

```js
function toggleDropdown(){
   document.getElementById('games-dropdown').classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
      display: none;
  }
```

```html
<li class="dropdown"><a onclick="toggleDropdown()">GAMES</a></li>
<div id="games-dropdown">
games-dropdown
</div>
```

You can also make your function more generic by accepting a selector for the element to show/hide:

```js
function toggleDropdown(selector) {
   document.querySelector(selector).classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
      display: none;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a onclick="toggleDropdown('#games-dropdown')">GAMES</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a onclick="toggleDropdown('#games-dropdown2')">GAMES2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="games-dropdown">
games-dropdown
</div>
<div id="games-dropdown2">
games-dropdown 2
</div>
```

I used `querySelector` rather than `getElementById` so you could use other forms of identifying the element, but of course use `getElementById` if ou prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that one seems to work!

Yeah, I will try and add the class as well. But this was a test, to see if I could make sense of it. Eventually I want to add a class that will trigger a CSS animation.

I'm trying to make this website: https://www.blizzard.com/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `classList.toggle` function. When the class is visible you can show the tag if not you can hide it.

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('games-dropdown').classList.toggle('someClass')
```

Comment: You mean as I did in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52556286/157247)? :-)

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning the value rather than comparing the value to style element

```
 <div id='games-dropdown'> Your Dropdown </div>

    <li class="dropdown"><a onClick="toggleDropdown()">GAMES</a></li>

    <script>
    function toggleDropdown(){

       var dropdown = document.getElementById('games-dropdown')

       if (dropdown.style.display == "none"){
        dropdown.style.display = 'block';
       } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
       }
    }
    </script>
```